# Let $f$ be a continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Then, $f$ is not necessarrily lipschitz.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Then, $f$ is not necessarily lipschitz.

Is the above statement true?

I thought since $f$ is continuous on a compact metric space, $f$ is bounded.
Thus $f'$ is also bounded, which implies that $f$ is lipschitz.

Is my argument correct? If not, where did I get wrong? Help me.

Comment: You're assuming that $f$ is differentiable

Comment: In addition, derivatives need not be bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A continuous function is not necessarily differentiable. In any case,  your argument would work if the function was *continuously* differentiable. For a counter example, take $\sqrt x$, for instance.